# run specific feature only, start some tests the first of all

Tags: java, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, thucydides

I have some questions:

1. I have some features in my tests, and some classes like NavigationTest, AuthorizationTest and etc.
   In my requirment class i have following:

   @Feature

   public class Navigation{}

   @Feature

   public class Authorization{}

   I want to run specific feature only, for example Navigation. How to do it? 
   I know i can put @Ignore in AuthorizationTest before each test, but i have a lot of tests and it is not nice solution. Is there any other ways to run only specific feature?
2. How to set some of my tests to be started first (before others) ?

Answer (score 3):

This has been implemented in Thucydides 0.9.116.

Add -Dtags=feature:someFeature or -Dtags=myTag:value,otherTag:value to run only those tests with a tag or tags.

Here's the specific commit:
https://github.com/thucydides-webtests/thucydides/commit/79634f5d30e8ae6affcdadc329d2bb67f061daff

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion on this topic [at goggle groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/thucydides-users/TsaIr-wxgpQ)

Feature request was created.